Compare 2 directories based on their folder structure in batch
I am working on a batch script that takes user input of a source folder and a destination folder. I want my script to iterate through both folder structures and log which folders are not present in either directory. I want to ignore the files in the folder and subfolders and only focus on the what folders are present. Currently I am trying to iterate through the source folder and compare each iteration to the destination folder and log whatever iteration does not match up, then I am doing the same with the destination folder and checking if there are any extra folders in the destination that are not in the source.
here is my script:
@echo off
setLocal enabledelayedexpansion
::asking user to input the folders to compare

set /p "sourceFolder=Enter Source Folder: "
echo.
set /p "destinationFolder=Enter Destination Folder: "

echo source: %sourceFolder%
echo destination: %destinationFolder%

REM Log file to store mismatched folders
@SET compareLog=%HOMEPATH%\mismatchLog_%COMPUTERNAME%_%CDATETIME%_.log
echo Mismatched folders between %sourceFolder% and %destinationFolder% > %compareLog%

::iterate through folder and compare structure
for /r "%sourceFolder%" %%i in (*.*) do (
    set "relativePath=%%i"
    set "relativePath=!relativePath:%sourceFolder%=!"


::check if same folder exists in destination

    if not exist "%destinationFolder%!relativePath!"(
    echo Folder missing in destinationFolder: !relativePath! >> %compareLog%
    )
)

::check for extra folders in destination

for /r "%destinationFolder%" %%i in (*.*) do (
    set "relativePath=%%i"
    set "relativePath=!relativePath:%destinationFolder%=!"

    if not exist "%sourceFolder%!relativePath!" (
        echo Extra Folder in destination: !relativePath! >> %compareLog%
    )
)

echo compare done
pause

There are currently no files in both the source and destination folder as I want this script to run before I add files to the destination folder to be able to check the structure beforehand. I am getting a Syntax error on the first for loop as well which I am confused by. Any help is appreciated, I hope I have provided enough information.
EDIT:
The intended task for my script is to compare the file structure of 2 directories that the user inputs the paths to. The folders and subfolders that are not present in the destination folder will be logged so one can go and check which folders are not present.
CHECK ANSWER FOR WORKING CODE THAT PERFORMS THE TASK

cmd is quite picky with spaces: give it one between " and ( (the if not exist line; like you did in the second loop)

The second line setLocal enabledelayedexpansion is already wrong as it results in processing directories with on or more ! in path wrong. Delayed variable expansion is needed with your approach, but should be used only within the FOR loops after execution of set "relativePath=%%i" and requires and endlocal in same FOR loop. echo. is in general not good as described by DosTips forum topic: ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/ as it always results in searching in current directory for file echo

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%sourceFolder%" /AD-L /B /S 2^>NUL') do ( results in processing just all directories including those with hidden attribute set with ignoring junctions and symbolic links to directories (remove -L to include them too). But best would be forgetting your approach, run in a command prompt window %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%sourceFolder%" "%destinationFolder%" /E /XF * /L /NFL /NJH /NJS and look on the output of ROBOCOPY. It outputs which extra folders exist only in source or only in destination directory.

See if the output of the single command robocopy /L /X /V /E /MIR /NP /NJH /NJS  %sourceFolder%" "%destinationFolder%" suits you.  (Edit: LOL @Mofi)

ATTENTION: The environment variables sourceFolder and destinationFolder must be without a backslash at the end on its reference being enclosed in ". Otherwise the backslash is interpreted as escape character by ROBOCOPY for the following " and the command line does not work. The root directory of a drive must be referenced with \ as C: is a relative path for current directory on drive C: while C:\ references the root directory of the drive C:. The root directory of a drive must be passed to ROBOCOPY without surrounding " like just C:\ or as "C:\\".

You would need to make sure that the user really entered folder paths (with a relative path or with a full path) and handle the special use case of root directory of a drive. For example, see How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input? After removal of double quotes and making sure with an IF condition that the entered string references an existing folder, there should be used a FOR command line to get the full path of the entered folder in case of a folder with relative path.

Thank you for the ROBOCOPY suggestion it works very well, it tells me exactly what directories are not found in the destination folder. Is there a way I can filter output results of the ROBOCOPY and only log the folders that were missing in the destination. This script will check huge directories so being able to filter only the folders that don't exist in destination is crucial. Sorry if that's a silly question.

See robocopy /? - the /L switch does List only, it doesn't actually copy.  Folders present in dest but not in source are marked as *ZUS. Verz. (in my German Windows - your string will be different), those present in source but not in dest are marked Neues Verz.. Easy to filter with | findstr /L /C:"*ZUS. Verz." /C:"Neues Verz." (both of them, or just one of them with just one "string to find".

Vielen lieben dank @Stephan

Your submitted code does not correlate with your stated task. You specifically said "I want to ignore the files in the folder and subfolders and only focus on the what folders are present." Then you proceeded to /recurse the directory tree, which clearly picks up subdirectories, (which is what I presume you mean by subfolders). It is essential that the task is explained properly in order for the question to be understood by potential helpers and future users of this site. Could you please therefore use the [Edit] facility to properly clarify the intended task for the resulting script.

Yes I dont care about files in the directory I am only worried about the subdirectories. The intended task of the script is to log the subdirectories that are not found in the destination directory. I am not sure how you want me to edit the question. Is it a problem that I was trying to use /r? As you said /r goes through the subdirectories which is what I was trying to do before being suggested to try robocopy. Either way I was able to fix my code and it performs the task correctly, I posted an Answer myself.

Could you please be more clear with what you mean Compo

In your original code: Note that ::check constitutes a(n unreachable) label. Within a code block (parenthesised sequence of statements), :: is NOT a comment, and needs to be replaced by rem.  Labels break code blocks.

Thanks to your input I was able to solve my problem and get the result I wanted. Here is the working code.
REM Asking user to input the folders to compare.

set /p "sourceFolder=Enter Source Folder: "
echo(
set /p "destinationFolder=Enter Destination Folder: "
echo(
echo source: %sourceFolder%
echo(
echo destination: %destinationFolder%
echo(

REM Log file to store mismatched folders
SET compareLog=%HOMEPATH%\missmatchLog_%COMPUTERNAME%_%CDATETIME%_WMS0.CFD.log
echo Mismatched folders between %sourceFolder% and %destinationFolder% > %compareLog%

REM robocopy lists the folders not found in the destination
%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe /l /x /v /e /mir /np /njh /njs %sourceFolder% %destinationFolder% | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /C:"New Dir" > %compareLog%
echo compare done

pause
exit /b


Instead of telling the user which folders to create manually - see xcopy /?, especially the /T /E switch combination (hint: recreating a folder structure without copying files; already existing subfolders at dest will not be deleted, even if they aren't in source).
